# Mostrar únicamente una pantalla Windows 10 con c#

Tags: c#, windows10, winapi

Es mi primera pregunta en este gran foro así que disculpas anticipadas por cualquier falta de explicación.

Me gustaría saber como puedo configurar únicamente una pantalla, como se realiza en la configuración de pantallas, pero mediante condigo c#.

Me gustaría hacer una función que recibiera el int del monitor y apagar los demás, esto desde código c# y windows 10.

Actualmente mi codigo establece un monitor como principal.

```
public static void DesconectarMonitor(int idMonitor)
    {

        uint id = Convert.ToUInt32(idMonitor);
        var device = new DISPLAY_DEVICE();
        var deviceMode = new DEVMODE();
        device.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(device);

        NativeMethods.EnumDisplayDevices(null, id, ref device, 0);
        NativeMethods.EnumDisplaySettings(device.DeviceName, -1, ref deviceMode);
        var offsetx = deviceMode.dmPosition.x;
        var offsety = deviceMode.dmPosition.y;
        deviceMode.dmPosition.x = 0;
        deviceMode.dmPosition.y = 0;

        NativeMethods.ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(
            device.DeviceName,
            ref deviceMode,
            (IntPtr)null,
            (ChangeDisplaySettingsFlags.CDS_SET_PRIMARY| ChangeDisplaySettingsFlags.CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY | ChangeDisplaySettingsFlags.CDS_NORESET),
            IntPtr.Zero);

        device = new DISPLAY_DEVICE();
        device.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(device);

        // Update remaining devices
        for (uint otherid = 0; NativeMethods.EnumDisplayDevices(null, otherid, ref device, 0); otherid++)
        {
            if (device.StateFlags.HasFlag(DisplayDeviceStateFlags.AttachedToDesktop) && otherid != id)
            {
                device.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(device);
                var otherDeviceMode = new DEVMODE();

                NativeMethods.EnumDisplaySettings(device.DeviceName, -1, ref otherDeviceMode);

                otherDeviceMode.dmPosition.x -= offsetx;
                otherDeviceMode.dmPosition.y -= offsety;

                NativeMethods.ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(
                    device.DeviceName,
                    ref otherDeviceMode,
                    (IntPtr)null,
                    (ChangeDisplaySettingsFlags.CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY | ChangeDisplaySettingsFlags.CDS_NORESET),
                    IntPtr.Zero);

            }

            device.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(device);
        }

        // Apply settings
        NativeMethods.ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(null, IntPtr.Zero, (IntPtr)null, ChangeDisplaySettingsFlags.CDS_NONE, (IntPtr)null);
    }
```

Un saludo y gracias por su tiempo

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes , puedes compartir el codigo que tienes hecho hasta el momento para tener un punto del que partir?

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta.

Comment: //Establece unicamente el monitor Interno
        public static void SetInternal()
        {}
        //Establece monitores extendidos 
        public static void ExtendDisplays()
        {}
        
        //Establece monitores clonados
        public static void CloneDisplays()
        {
               }
        //Establece unicamente el montiror Externo
        public static void ExternalDisplay()
        { }
        Puedo también establecer un monitor como principal pero no encuentro como realizar la petición de desconectar la pantalla.

Un saludo!

Comment: Dentro de las funciones realizo peticiones a la api mediante la librerira User32 algo así-->
SetDisplayConfig(0, IntPtr.Zero, 0, IntPtr.Zero, (uint)(SDC.SDC_APPLY | SDC.SDC_TOPOLOGY_INTERNAL));

Comment: Utiliza el boton de editar tu pregunta y añade el codigo que pones en los comentarios, asi los proximos que entren no tendran que leer todos los comentarios y tendran toda la informacion en un solo sitio, ademas de que es mas organizado :)

Comment: Gracias ya esta hecho.

Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Puedes obtener la información del sistema operativo con:

```
OperatingSystem os_info = System.Environment.OSVersion;
```

y ese objeto `os_info` tiene distintas propiedades, entre ellas la versión del sistema operativo. Con un condicional del tipo `if(os_info.Version == "10.0")` lo que se ejecute dentro solo debería ser en el sistema de windows 10.

Comment: Mi objetivo es desconectar una pantalla en concreto realizando una peticion a la api de windows con c#.

Un saludo